# When you use Simulink to generate C code, do you perform unit testing on the generated code or Simulink model or both? Does it make sense to do both?

Tags: unit-testing, simulink, v-model

When you consider the V-model, implementation is at the bottom. If you have created your component design (detailed design) using Simulink, then your generated code can be considered as 'implementation' (right?). Now if you want to perform unit testing (first step on the right side of the V-model), do you perform unit testing on the Simulink model units or do you perform the unit testing on the generated C-code units? Or do you have to cover both?

Comment: Model testing will verify high level requirements early in the project before you have gone through to the code generation step.

Comment: Depending on your industry, you may be able to claim partial credit for the model testing but you will likely have to run at least a subset of your tests on the real code to satisfy test coverage objectives. This would certainly be the case in aerospace under DO-178C.